# XYZ has been attracting increasing attention vs attracting increased attention

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

I recently read two documents where I saw:

- XYZ has been attracting **increasing** attention.
- XYZ has been attracting **increased** attention.

Are both correct? Is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, but the meaning is slightly different.  You can tell by the tense.

The sentence with **increasing** indicates that the attention is increasing now, and will likely continue in the future.  (It might not, but we're implying we think it will)

The sentence with **increased** says that the attention has increased but we don't necessarily expect the attention to increase more from now on.  (It might, but we aren't implying it will)